# Impact of Node.js upgrade in a serverless application

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, node-modules, upgrade, aws-serverless

I have a Node.js application that uses AWS serverless architecture.
Currently I'm using an old version of Node.js but need to upgrade to the latest version that AWS supports (Node.js 18.x).
What could be the impact of such an upgrade?

I just update the version in `serverless.yml` file and seems to be ok, but still have some doubts if this could have a negative impact or not.

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x
```

Answer (score 0):

The impact of that change is kind of hard to tell. The obvious thing to do is [regression testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing), assuming you have tests.
You can also deploy a second application with the new version of Node and split a tiny portion of the traffic to it (Blue/Green deployment) and look for errors.

Comment: So regression testing is a must in such a case...